# How to give 404 status in the home page and also display the page

Tags: hyperlink, seo, joomla1.5

In April my site was penalized by Penguin update(on 24th April). Due to JV Links I got lot of backlinks from nasty places although I did not linkback to any.

Now last month I've disavoved almost all domains but instead of ranking higher, the traffic seems to have dropped.

All the backlinks point to the home page so I want to display the home page as it is but also give the 404 error code when it is accessed. That'll dilute the backlink penalty to home page.

How can I do it easily in Joomla site?

Reference : http://www.seroundtable.com/404-links-google-15427.html

Comment: The article you linked to is talking about *removing* the content and returning a 404 status code, and even then advises against doing it.

Comment: I want to keep the content so that viewers are not affected. I'm taking this last step before I change my domain.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to kill your website?

Penguin has either devalued your backlinks or caused them to harm you. You will not get back to where you were originally from your current links. Those days have gone.

Disavowing may protect you from the ones that were harmful, but it also removes any little link juice that was remaining. So you will probably drop rankings from doing disavows unless the act does switch off penguin. And you won't know that until the next Penguin update.

Making you home page return a 404 will just get it de-indexed and you will lose everything.

The advice in the article assumes your talking about a page you can live without, and kill. Your home page is not one of them.

I'd suggest you sit still until the next Penguin update and see if you're disavows cleared it up. Or focus on improving your website via content that will earn you the links you want.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, any idea about next Penguin update? I just saw similar views : http://www.seroundtable.com/google-ranking-manual-action-16013.html

Comment: It's going to be next Thursday. (If I'm right someone owes me a pint)